# AJAX call fails with Django. No response or error message

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$.post("register/email", { email:"myemail" }, function(data,status){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

and my views.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

def registerEmail(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            email = request.POST['email'];
            return HttpResponse(email)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Game')
```

and my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', homePageView, name='home'),
    path('register/email/', registerEmail, name='verifyEmail'),
]
```

I get no alert message when executing the page. Plus, no error message in ajax or django. 
So i tried adding alert('hello') outside the ajax get function, inside $(document).ready, and i got a hello message as expected. So my js files are linked correctly in django. my js files are located in `myproject/currentapp/static/currentapp/js`. I am new to django, so please suggest me if i need to add more information before asking for a solution.

Comment: If you didn't see the `alert()` then there will have been an error on the server side. I'd suggest making the request and checking the 'network' tab of the console to see what the exact status code and response text is. That should give you a clue as to exactly what part of your Python code needs debugging.

Comment: There is one obvious error, which is that you are sending a GET but in the view you try and access a key of `request.POST`, which will be empty.

Comment: @ShafikurRahman tried it. Still no response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i checked the network tab. There's no request made for /register/email page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh sorry i forgot to edit views.py after i changed my code from post to get to check what's wrong.

Comment: In which case your AJAX call is not being made. You've not shown under what event it should be, but that is what you now need to debug

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan edited my question

Comment: Are you certain the request isn't made? You're doing it when the page loads, so the only way it wouldn't appear is if jQuery wasn't loaded, but there would be a very obvious console error if that was the case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't know if it is made, i am a newbie. But the jquery is loaded, i checked it by placing alert('hello') before the ajax function call and it worked as expected. Plus, i checked the network tab and it shows Error 505 internal server error for this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/email

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the first comment. Your call is being made and is resulting in the 505 error on the server. This means there is an error in your Python code and the JS is fine. You need to debug the Python to see what the problem is. Note that a 505 error is very rare, it means you're using the wrong version of HTTP for the request: https://httpstatuses.com/505. Double check t ensure that is the correct error code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried adding a slash at the end of the url in the ajax request. Now, it no longer shows internal server error, but it says CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: That error is self explanatory.